# Send form to address based on response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Sheet that is linked with a basic Google form. I want to be able to select a name from the form and once submitted, it automatically send to an address based on the conditions I define.
E.g., if Ronald McDonald is selected in the form, then the script says that it should send to Ronald.mcdonald@example.com

The addresses are NOT within the form. - Just the names. I'd like the script to contain the addresses.

This is the first thing I'm attempting to build with app script. I can't find much online to figure out where to start.

Would very much like some help.

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZbUQ7HlY9BB3iKiLPcKAYnYry9EesvCzLs2zWz0PdMI/edit?usp=sharing

Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/19PmNlsFEHptmviafFgG6Qc077dOLXK8Yw1NOj3lJ7sk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide a first mockup of your form and spreadsheet. The solution is to use onFormSubmit with a trigger

Comment: @Mike Steelson
 See below. I've also added into my original post.

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZbUQ7HlY9BB3iKiLPcKAYnYry9EesvCzLs2zWz0PdMI/edit?usp=sharing

Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/19PmNlsFEHptmviafFgG6Qc077dOLXK8Yw1NOj3lJ7sk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this please add the more relevant details of the linked documents. Note: When adding code, add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first with this generic code

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  if (responses["Agent Name"][0] == 'Ronald Mcdonald') {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: '###########@gmail.com',
      subject: 'new informations',
      htmlBody: JSON.stringify(responses)
    });
  }
}
```

and put a trigger

### edit

to take into account the list of emails, try (please initialize first to activate the trigger)

```
function initialize() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onFormSubmit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
  }
  console.log('Your script has been initialized!')
}
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email contact')
    .getDataRange().getValues()
    .filter(r => r[0] == responses["Agent Name"][0])
  if (email.length != 1) { return } // email found (unique)
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email[0][1],
    subject: 'new informations',
    htmlBody: '<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr>' + Object.keys(responses).map(h => '<td>' + h + '</td><td>' + (Array.isArray(responses[h]) ? responses[h].join(",") : responses[h]) + '</td>').join('</tr><tr>') + '</tr></table>'
  });
}
```

Comment: How does that code define which address to send it to? In my head it would need a list of the different email variables for each name selected?

Comment: yes you are right, you need to put the list inside a tab in your spreadsheet. Please, define the list and I will complete the code.

Comment: Thank you. I've created the list in a the tab called 'Email contact'.

Comment: Thank you. - I've tried using this now on the actual 'live form'. But am getting the error below within the execution logs. Everything is pretty much the same, except instead of "Agent Name", it's "Advisor Name". I've updated this in the script though. -  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at [unknown function](Code:14:51)
    at onFormSubmit(Code:14:6)

Comment: Take core to write Advisor Name exatly identical to the title of the question, including space, underscore, capitals ... make sure there is no additionnal space at the end of the title for instance.

Comment: I've managed to get it working now. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const eobj = {"Ronald McDonald":"Ronald.McDonald@example.com","Fred Smith":"foolish.freddy@jackass.com"};
  if(eobj.hasOwnProperty(e.values[1])) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(eboj[e.values[1]],"Subject","Message")
  }
}

function createOnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onFormSubmit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

You will have to fill in the eobj with all the the names as properties and values as email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the previous answers: When the script runs as a different (service) user the outgoing mail that is processed by apps script is labelled as sent by this very user identity. AFAIK there is no way to let the form respondent appear as the sender of the mail. The least you can do about it is setting the mail's alias and the reply-to with the responent's mail address like this:

```
let ffForm           = FormApp.openById("123xcvdag71orwhatever");
let formResponses    = ffForm.getResponses()[ffForm.getResponses().length -1];
let userMailAddress  = formResponses.getRespondentEmail();

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to:        varWhoever,
  subject:   varSubject,
  name:      userMailAddress,
  replyTo:   userMailAddress}
);
```